# Using Bazel to build an Angular7 project

Tags: angular, bazel

I have gone through the example shown here - https://github.com/angular/angular-bazel-example

I am still unclear on how to get an Angular7 project built with Bazel. The requirements that I have are

1. From the Angular project run (somehow), `ng build --prod` to generate the `dist` folder that will be served by nginx.
2. This Angular project is a small portion of a massive outer shell project whose build is orchestrated through Bazel. So I am kind of forced to use Bazel from the front end.

On the sample project (angular-bazel-example), when I execute `bazel build //src:bundle`, I get a distribution that does not even have an index.html. Now what I expect is the result of `ng build --prod` (AOT) under my project so that I can handoff the `dist` folder for deployment (with nginx/tomcat or whatever).

It appears that Bazel and CLI are competing to build Angular. Any pointers to some real AOT `dist` from Bazel from an Angular project would be very helpful. If Bazel can do it, it leaves me wondering why they can't integrate this into the CLI itself (ng commands).